# Can I mention an attachment in my comments/activity on Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Is it possible to mention an attachment when you are adding comments/activity just like you can mention other members and cards?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, of course.

In the attachment section within the card, each attached file have a **comment button**. You just:

1. Click on the comment button of the attachment
2. The comment form will have the Markdown (for example filename.png) that you should copy and paste in the description or task in a checklist

Answer (score 2):

When you change anything in a card it is automatically shown as an activity.

There isn't a way to specifically mention an attachment, but you can mention a member anywhere by using @MemberName. So you can just say something like:

> @John Doe, check attachment WireFrame.Jpg

Or

> @John Doe, check my last activity (being that it was the attachment)

Answer (score 0):

First you should find the actual link of the image by Ctrl+Click, Copy the image url, Then 
add the image as follows.

```
This is an [image.png](https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/*****************/image.png)
```

The text will looks like

This is an [image.png](https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/*****************/image.png)

and when click on the image.png the image will get open as a popup.